# What does this response from recruitment chair mean: "Unfortunately I have no information to share at this point, but will let you know as soon I can"

Tags: faculty-application

I had in-person interview for a tenure track faculty position with great feedback from the search committee and even the chair. They mentioned that I am a good fit for their position and they are excited that I applied. They mentioned their timeline for making an offer which was 1 week from now. However I haven't heard anything from them yet. I asked the search committee chair about the probable decision but he replied "Unfortunately I have no information to share at this point, but will let you know as soon I can". What does this mean? Are they rejecting me?

Comment: I would love to someday experience living in a culture where when people say “I have no information to share” everyone understands this to mean something completely different. Sadly, in my boring culture it just means what it says…

Comment: Thank you. I like this kind of answers because they relief stress

Answer (score 11):

It means they have no information to share at this point regarding their decision, and that you will be informed as soon as they know otherwise, exactly like the committee chair's words say. Presumably that's because they haven't made the decision.

If you keep pestering them, maybe they'll decide to reject you based on that.

I would very strongly recommend against trying to read secret signals that let you know what someone's decision is going to be. Positive feedback does not guarantee you a job - hiring decisions often come down to a choice between more than one candidate that the hiring committee would very much like to hire, yet they have only one position available. Delays do not mean a rejection, they often come because busy people have to meet with each other; meetings can be delayed because of unexpected events.

Continue seeking other positions until you have accepted a formal offer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

It means exactly what they said.  They have not made a decision yet.  Even if the search committee has decided on their recommendation, it would be irresponsible for them to tell you anything until it has been approved by enough higher-ups to make a change in the decision highly unlikely.

With the holidays coming up, realistically, you should forget about the whole thing and expect to hear back some time in mid-January.

If you have another offer or some actual reason you *need* to know, then tell them.

Otherwise, go meditate or work on your next paper.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot to understand

Answer (score 3):

That means the search committee chair hasn't heard from the decision makers about their final decision.

I had gone through ​​a​​ similar situation a few days back. I had an interview, where I could sense 50% chance of them selecting me. Over time they confirmed rejection for all other candidates except me. Keeping patience in this type of situation is really ​​tough. However at the end of that worrisome period, I got to know they selected me.

I would suggest (in order to forget this worry), assume they might not select, and continue with your other interviews. In case they get back with positive decision, that will be a sweet surprise to you. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for this input....I really appreciate your comment......this helps me to relief some stress......if they wont select me the feeling will not be so hard for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the scenarios already raised is the possibility that you are on the list of people they want but not ranked number 1. In my institution we usually send a list of acceptable candidates, from those who had visits, to the Provost. At that point there are various discussions and then negotiations with the first person start. At that point we are giving vague answers to  the other acceptable candidates because fairly regularly the first one does not work out. But we'd be happy with anyone on the final list.

Comment: Thank you, this was my thought from all other clues in their previous emails.